# Implement SDIO to interface SPI device

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, microcontroller, sd-card, spi

People,

I have always seen references about how to use a SPI interface to operate a SD memory card.
This is **not** what I want. I need to do exactly the opposite.

I want to be able to use the SDIO controller (through SD slot) in my "host" (any PC having a SD-card interface) to talk to my devices (basically microcontrollers) that can only "speak" SPI.

If my understanding is not too wrong, I cannot simply tell my SD controller to talk in a raw SPI mode but I can teach my microcontrollers to behave as a SDIO device that can be controlled by my host.

This way I still have two challenges left:

1. Correctly implement a generic SDIO device in my microcontroller.
2. Implement/configure the correct drivers in the host to be able to interact with my devices.

Implement the SDIO device **seems** to be a matter of following the [spec](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/sdio/sdio_spec/Simplified_SDIO_Card_Spec.pdf).
The host-side driver, though, is something I hope I can accomplish with a user-space driver in Linux using some already existing kernel-space driver to SDIO.

That's the point that I come to ask for help.
Can anyone please point me any samples, documents or any kind of resources that can help me in my task?

Comment: I doubt there are many people around here who understand how the SDIO stack works in Linux (and a driver using SDIO should behave). I'd definitely look them up and ask them directly, or via their mailing list. As a starting point: http://sdio-linux.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

On the PC side, this is all you need:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdio-linux/

This may be useful for reference: http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/WritingLinuxSDIODrivers.htm  (although, I don't think you would be writing a driver)

On the microcontroller side, use "bit-banging" to implement the SDIO spec.

However, first consider why do this.  SDIO and SPI are just serial protocols, so is USB; wouldn't you rather make an SPI-to-USB bridge?  USB is much more user-friendly on the host side, as well as being more standard/more common.  And if you do want a SPI-to-USB bridge, turns out it already exists, the [SPI Shortcut](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9235) (probably other options, this is just the first one that comes to mind)

*EDIT* Or, you could bit-bang I2C on the micro, if the host supports I2C (many do).  Actually, go through every serial protocol the host supports, and see if you can support it easily from the micro side (by bit banging, since the micro is likely to not have a slave mode for that protocol built-in).  RS232 (with level shifter), I2C, and SPI are likely to be the preferred choices.  SDIO is pretty much the last choice, I think.

Comment: My customer doesn't want to add any additional hardware to bridge the host to its devices. I am pretty sure that an USB/RS232 converter would do the job very easily but customer is not yet convinced that a standard converter like FTDI, Microchip or Prolific are worth the price. They don't trust this solution and they have their reasons so I still have to dig a little more on this SDIO/SPI possibility. Thanks!

Comment: @fljx: Okay, I see.  One more option: you could have your host device talk I2C to your micro, and do I2C slave by bit-banging on the micro?  This is likely to be 1000% easier than SDIO also.  I guess what I mean is, go through every single serial protocol that your host supports, and compare how easy it is to do the micro side.  SDIO is gotta be among the hardest, I would steer you away from that.

Comment: Alex, thank you once more. On the slave side I don't need to bit-bang if I can have I2C on the master. The microcontroller has I2C in hardware. The question is, how to make the host (an x86 based hardware) to talk I2C through the SDIO interface?

Comment: You could use the hidden I2C interface inside of the VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

SDIO is very tightly specified. Unless your microcontroller has an SDIO block that is designed to act as a device rather than host, I don't think this will be possible. I know of a few special purpose communications controllers that implement an SDIO device, but I haven't come across any general purpose microcontrollers.

You would need a fairly fast microcontroller to be able to bit-bang SDIO initialization at up to 400 kHz. If running an STM32F4 at 180 MHz, this gives you only microcontroller cycles between SDIO clock cycles. If the host turns up the clock speed to the maximum of 25 MHz after initialization, then you're down to 7 cycles between SDIO clocks.

For perspective on the SDIO spec, the one you linked is a simplified spec that doesn't cover the signalling and timing of the bus. The full spec is many times larger.

As Alex I mentioned, there may be better alternatives for what you need. If your SDIO host supports SPI mode, most microcontrollers do have SPI peripherals that can act as slaves rather than hosts, so this may be an avenue without a peripheral. If your data rates are low enough, a simple UART may suffice (you can reasonably hit 1 Mbit over short distances).

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough but what I want is exactly using SDIO from a host to talk with SPI microcontrollers. I never said that I plan to implement bit-banging SDIO in a microcontroller. If you have any advises on how to put a Host SDIO controller to talk to a SPI device, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: I think I'm still not understanding. You have a host PC and you want to use SDIO to communicate to SPI microcontrollers? You have two different communication interfaces that you are trying to link up, and I don't think you'll be able to make it work without creating some sort of bridge device.

Comment: 1. SDIO protocol defines an SPI mode, right? 2. Devices having SPI interface can talk with SDIO host if it obbeys the SDIO protocol IN SPI MODE, right?

Comment: You would have to investigate whether your SDIO host supports SPI mode. I believe the SPI mode is for hosts without full SDIO support to communicate with SDIO devices, not intended to work the other way.

Comment: @fljx I understand very well what you are trying to do and think it's clearly stated. My question is, have you tried it out or even achieved it?

Comment: Hello @vanthome, unfortunately not. After some time struggling I could not get enough information/help and we followed another approach adding an additional hardware to comunicate to the old host through USB-to-CANbus.